# Are there more Singular or non-singular matrix? And does non-singular infer linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix A = M x M is called singular if it doesn't have an inverse and the determinant of A = 0;

A squared matrix A will be non-singular if its invertible and has det(A) !=0;

My question is:

1. Are there more singular or non-singular matrix? I am guessing there should be more non-singular matrix because you can easily have det(A) !=0.
2. Furthermore, are all the row/column vectors in singular matrix linearly independent?
3. Does it imply that a singular matrix doesn't have eigenvalue?

Comment: It's actually singular when it doesn't have an inverse and non-singular when it does have an inverse.

Comment: One has to define "more." If it is in the sense of cardinality, then for infinite fields the numbers are "the same," except for $1\times 1$ matrices. For finite fields, your intuition is right.

Comment: non-singular should be banned from math books, use either regular or invertible (because that's what people mean by "non-singular")

Comment: @OskarLimka Agreed, so many unnecessary definition for the same concepts

Comment: @rVitale You are correct, non-singular means invertible and singular means non-invertible.

Answer (score 3):

(We're assuming entries in a field, if this makes no sense don't worry about it)

A singular matrix is **not** invertible and has determinant equal to 0.  A non-singular matrix is invertible and has determinant not equal to 0.

1. There are a lot more non-singular matrices than singular ones in the following precise sense.  Think of an $m \times m$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{m^2}$.  The determinant is a polynomial function $\mathbb{R}^{m^2} \xrightarrow{\det} \mathbb{R}$, so the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{m^2} | \det(x)=0 \}$ is the zero set of a single polynomial in $m^2$ variables and defines a hypersurface.  Everything not on that hypersurface (almost everything, think of a curve in the plane or a surface in $3$-space) is non-singular
2. The two statements 'the matrix has non-zero determinant' and 'the vectors making up the columns/rows of the matrix are independent' are equivalent.

Comment: As André Nicolas says in the comments though, the sets have the same cardinality.  My 'more' is in the sense of measure.